# Linux: Re-establishing serial ports after they're lost

Tags: linux, bash, serial-port

I have a network that's stitched together using USB (the master computer sends out data to the slaves via USB and vice versa). The master computer is a Linux machine (Raspberry Pi) and the slaves are teensy boards.

My problem is that over time, the master computer "loses sight" of the slave's serial ports (ACM1, ACM2 .... ACMn) as they remain plugged in, i.e., at indeterminate times, ACM1 might disappear, or ACM2 might. I checked and the slaves aren't losing power. I figured there must be some way to communicate to the operating system to re-establish connection to the devices (without just cycling the power of the devices). Or perhaps to just re-establish connection to all USB devices. Is there such a way?

Please, let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: What happens exactly when the master "loses sight" of the slaves? You said it isn't a power issue, do you know what the issue is?

Comment: Let's say when I start the program, I have available [ACM1, ACM2, ACM3, ACM4]. I restart the program every six hours, and I will indeterminately have less ports available to me, and they will be named differently [ACM4, ACM5, ACM6]. I need to remove that issue and have the same ports available when I startup again. The power to the devices does get cycled, but I am waiting a good 10 seconds before checking they're availability to make sure they can be seen.

Comment: Which RPi is this? Older spins have a fuse that limits USB current even if the full 500mA is requested.

Comment: Try looking through the /sys file system.  You may be able to use the path to reconcile the device.